# Как считывать данные с помощью ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, io

Есть метод для чтения массива байтов из потока, но он почему-то прочитывает только последнюю ячейку в массиве.
Что я делаю неправильно?

```
public void read() {
    byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Печатает в консоль только цифру `4`. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `read` возвращает количество прочитанных байт, поэтому возвращается значение `4`.
Кроме того, значения кладутся в тот же массив, из которого читаются. Это к тому, что чтобы проверить что что-то прочиталось, нужно взять другой массив. Например:

```
byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] out = new byte[4];
try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
    int b;
    while ((b = in.read(out)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
```

Теперь в массиве `out` четыре прочитанных байта.